# Make omission in ruby truncate a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to make the omission "..." a link for my truncated ruby string. Here's what I have:

```
  <%= truncate(testimony.testimony, :length => 125, :omission => (link_to "...", testimony)) %><br />
```

but it does this:

```
Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur<a href="/testimonies/1">...</a>
```

Rather than making the actual ... a link it shows the code. See: http://cl.ly/4Wy3 for the screenshot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that truncate santizes the output , you need to use `raw()` as in the docs below:

> The result is not marked as HTML-safe, so will be subject to the default escaping when used in views, unless wrapped by raw(). Care should be taken if text contains HTML tags or entities, because truncation may produce invalid HTML (such as unbalanced or incomplete tags).

EDIT example:

```
<%= raw(truncate(testimony.testimony, :length => 125, :omission => (link_to "...", testimony))) %><br />
```

Comment: Great. So how would I use it in this case?

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked great!

Answer (score 4):

```
<%= truncate(testimony.testimony, :length => 125, :omission => "%s") % link_to("...", testimony) %>
```

Comment: actually it still came out like: Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur<a href="/testimonies/1">...</a>

Comment: % is interpolation. Probably, the `truncate` helper doesn't return a safe string. You should use `raw` to avoid escaping.

Comment: So how would I implement using `raw`?

Comment: Just put `raw` before `truncate` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RawOutputHelper.html#method-i-raw