# Rails truncate helper with link as omit text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, truncate

I'm quite long description that I want to truncate using truncate helper. 
So i'm using the:

```
truncate article.description, :length => 200, :omission => ' ...'
```

The problem is that I want to use more as a clickable link so in theory I could use this:

```
truncate article.description, :length => 200, :omission => "... #{link_to('[more]', articles_path(article)}"
```

Omission text is handled as unsafe so it's escaped. I tried to make it html_safe but it didn't work, instead of link [more] my browser is still showing the html for that link.

Is there any way to force truncate to print omission link instead of omission text?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make omission in ruby truncate a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964073/make-omission-in-ruby-truncate-a-link)

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest doing this on your own in a helper method, that way you'll have a little more control over the output as well:

```
def article_description article
  output = h truncate(article.description, length: 200, omission: '...')
  output += link_to('[more]', article_path(article)) if article.description.size > 200
  output.html_safe
end
```

Comment: @Pam-Thomakos This works great exept for one problem. When I click on the link it goes to posts.1 instead of post/1.

Comment: It should be singular `article_path` instead of the plural `articles_path`

Comment: What does the `h` before truncate do?

Answer (score 11):

With Rails 4, you can/should pass in a block for the link:

```
truncate("Once upon a time in a world far far away", 
  length: 10, 
  separator: ' ', 
  omission: '... ') {     
    link_to "Read more", "#" 
}
```

Comment: This is what did it for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Dirty solution... use the method "raw" to unescape it.
you have to be sure of "sanity" of your content.

```
raw(truncate article.description, :length => 200, :omission => "... #{link_to('[more]', articles_path(article)}")
```

raw is a helper acting like html_safe .
bye

edit: is not the omission of being escaped , but the result of truncate method.

Comment: The problem is that i cannot be sure of the sanity of article.description

Answer (score 4):

I encountered a similar situation and this did the trick. Try (line breaks for readability):

```
(truncate h(article.description), 
                  :length => 200, 
                  :omission => "... #{link_to('[more]',articles_path(article)}")
                  .html_safe
```

You can use h to ensure sanity of article description, and since you are setting the link_to to a path you know to not be something potentially nefarious, you can mark the resulting string as html_safe without concern.

Comment: You'll need to be careful to pass in `escape: false`, at least as of Rails 4.0.1, since [`TextHelper#truncate` will add its own escaping](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/58ab79ff9b34c22c3477e29763fdd4f4612e938d/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb#L92) to the concatenation of `h(article.description)` and the `omission` text. No amount of `.html_safe` will prevent it.

Answer (score 2):

`TextHelper#truncate` has a [block form of `truncate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate), which lets you use a `link_to` that isn't escaped, while still escaping the truncated text:

```
truncate("<script>alert('hello world')</script>") { link_to "Read More", "#" }

#=> &lt;script&gt;alert(&#39;hello world&#39;...<a href="#">Read More</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only one that worked for me :

```
<%= truncate(@article.content, length: 200, omission: " ... %s") % link_to('read more', article_path(@article)) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, in my case i just used `:escape => false`. 
That worked:

`truncate article.description, :length => 200, :omission => "... #{link_to('[more]', articles_path(article)}", :escape => false`

From documentation :

> The result is marked as HTML-safe, but it is escaped by default, unless :escape is false....
>   link: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/truncate