# Ruby on Rails Truncate Read More

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, truncate, expand

In my app, I have a comments section with a body.

```
<p><%= truncate(comment.body, length: 550) %>   <%= link_to "Read More" %></p>
```

I currently have this code to only show a portion of the comment's body, but when in the Link_to, when the user clicks on Read More, it disables the truncate method and show the full body

How would I go by doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [readmore-rails gem](https://github.com/seankay/readmorejs-rails) for nice toggle of long text.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('article').readmore({
          collapsedHeight: 218,
        });
        $('article').readmore({
          collapsedHeight: 218,
        });
        $('article').removeClass('hidden');
    });
</script>


  <article>
    <%= @post.text.html_safe %>
  </article>
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to achieve this using truncate, you'll need the entire string and then hide part of it using Javascript. When a user clicks the Read More link, you would use Javascript to show the hidden part.

There's a good explanation in a previous question [jQuery text truncation (read more style)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248742/jquery-text-truncation-read-more-style)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262503/rails-truncate-with-a-read-more-toggle

This seems to work perfectly, don't know why I hadn't found it before asking this question, Thanks Anyways!